# Computer Science - final year project being too focused on the engineering

Tags: computer-science, engineering, science, academic-freedom

Recently, I had 3 proposals for my final year project rejected as they were too focused on the engineering aspect of my course and less on terms of being academic?

What could possibly they (the final year project supervisors) mean? Do they mean by academic that I have to do a more research related work? And if it is so, how in the world am I supposed to come up with such a project(as that could be absolutely anything)?

I am so lost about this...

Comment: What were your 3 proposals so far?

Comment: Sounds like a great question for your project supervisors! It's also outside the scope of this site, which is for discussion of careers in academics.

Comment: It took them over a month to reply to me with useless statements, similar to the aforementioned "Your proposal suggests that your project is more focused on the engineering side, which would give you lower grades. Think of something better.", what would better mean.

Comment: If your proposals are along the lines of building X (which is engineering) then perhaps you could reframe it as a study of the best ways to build X or investigating the theory behind X or a study of the performance characteristics of X. I think what they are after is more science.

Comment: My first proposal was to create rc car with cameras attached to it which was to be controlled by micro controller, also the car would have a night vision camera (designed and built by me). (branded as too engineering focused)

2nd projects was too similar to what a colleague of mine was doing. It was about using a microcontroller with photosensitive peripheral attached.(branded as unintentional plagiarism)

3rd project was to create  a tutorial/slash walkthrough of creating an operating system based on Linux. (branded as too engineering focused again)

Comment: @MarkWassell This is exactly what I am doing, however whatever I propose seems to be too technical and not academic enough (whatever that really means really)....

Comment: What kinds of guidelines have you been given about selecting a project?  Do you have any examples of projects other students have done?

Comment: What's your department? EE or CS or something else?

Comment: This is one of the things that bug me. We have been given complete "freedom" of choice when it comes to our project and for examples had such great variety it was mind boggling - from someone creating a varitaion of lisp written entirely in Hangul(Korean alphabet) characters to someone creating a microcontroller controlled fuel consumption device for lawn mowers.  When you see what other people are doing you would think that the final year project are more likely testing what you have learned so far and demonstrating it with your skills, but apparently this is not the case....

Comment: @schaaahu Computer Science

Comment: From the description of your project proposals, I really thought you're in EE. That's why I asked what department you're in. I must say that you really should have proposed more theoretical oriented project because you're in a _science_ department, not an _engineering_ one.

Comment: Computer Science is an Engineering discipline. Albeit some schools may focus more on the science than the (software) engineering.

Comment: Precisely my point. So far, I have lived with the notion that a final year project should be something of a proof of what you have learned throughout the years for you bachelors. Doing academical research seems to me is more of a masters or a PHD type of a project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have heard this kind of comment before as well, and then it meant that the proposed work was too much about (solving) implementation aspects, too little about novel 'research' or 'scientific' work.

It helps to ask the question: 'could this work potentially be published in a scientific venue (workshop, conference, journal, etc)?
If the answer is 'no', then it might be considered to be too much about engineering.

For the record: it is not my opinion that 'engineering' work is less valuable or educational than 'scientific' work. Or that there is even a clear distinction. I just want to shed some light on what people mean when they say these kind of things.

Comment: A really good answer indeed. Now I will only have to struggle with finding something "academical" to do as a project.